# How to pull data point from Firebase using Obj-C?

Tags: objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm saving a users zip code to the Firebase database and want to query that database on app launch to see if the user has input their zip code already or if they're a brand new user.

I've posted my code before. I pulled the sample code from the Firebase docs, but it seems that my app is never even running the following code to get the value

```
[[[_ref child:@"user"] child:userID] observeSingleEventOfType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {...
```

What am I missing out on?

```
#import "FollowingVC.h"
#import <FirebaseDatabase/FirebaseDatabase.h>
@import Firebase;

@interface FollowingVC ()

@property NSString *uid;
@property FIRDatabaseReference *ref;
@property NSString *zipcode;

@end

@implementation FollowingVC

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self createAuthorizedUser];
    [self checkForZipCode];
}

-(void)createAuthorizedUser
{
    [[FIRAuth auth]
     signInAnonymouslyWithCompletion:^(FIRUser *_Nullable user, NSError *_Nullable error) {
         if (!error) {
             self.uid = user.uid;

             self.ref=[[FIRDatabase database]reference];
             }
     }];
}

-(void)checkForZipCode
{
    NSString *userID = [FIRAuth auth].currentUser.uid;
    [[[_ref child:@"user"] child:userID] observeSingleEventOfType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {
        // Get user value
        self.zipcode = snapshot.value[@"zip code"];

        NSLog(@"It worked: %@", self.zipcode);

        // ...
    } withCancelBlock:^(NSError * _Nonnull error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
    }];

}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase is asynronous and you need to allow time for events to complete before moving on in the app.

In this case,  you should call [self checkForZipCode] inside the sign-in block after self.uid is populated.

Otherwise you run the risk of the checkForZipCode function running before the self.uid is populated.

Let Firebase control the flow of the app - and don't try to use Firebase synchronously as it will get you into trouble due to internet lag etc.